# String Comparison in C++ with IF Statements?

Tags: c++, compare, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I'm very new to C++, just started learning using an online course about 30 minutes ago. I'm a little confused as to why this string comparison isn't working in a basic math script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int one, two, answer;
  char *oper;

  cout << "Add two numbers\n\nEnter your first number" << endl;
  cin >> one;
  cout << "Choose an operator: +  -  *  /  %%" << endl;
  cin >> oper;

  cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;
  cin >> two;

  if (oper == "+") {
    answer = one + two;
  }
  else if (oper == "-") {
    answer = one - two;
  }
  else if (oper == "*") {
    answer = one * two;
  }
  else if (oper == "/") {
    answer = one / two;
  }
  else if (oper == "%%") {
    answer = one % two;
  }

  cout << one << " " << oper << " " << two << " = " << answer << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The values for `one`, `oper`, and `two` are `1`, `"+"`, and `1` respectively, but in the end, `1 + 1 = 4201435` is printed out. None of the `if`/`else if` statements are being executed. What's causing this?

Comment: `oper == "+"` compares pointer not string as `oper` is `char*`.

Comment: Using `cin >> oper` assumes `oper` points to an appropriate buffer. Yours is uninitialized. In fact, given that this is user input, there's no way to know whether the buffer is appropriate. Never do this. This is a non-issue if you use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing `char *` using `operator==`. Either let `oper` be a `std::string` instead

`std::string oper`

To use the string comparison listed here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

or if you need to use a `char *` for some restriction, use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

```
if (!strcmp(oper, "+")) {
// ...
```

You also need to have your operand variable point at some buffer too, for the stream to read into. This is a little bit more complicated and I just recommend changing the type of `oper` to `std::string`.

The problem with the code you have is that it's comparing pointers to char arrays. What you get from your input methods is going to be a new string from the input stream and will never have the same address as the readonly strings in your program.

So since none of the condition is `true`, ans hasn't been assigned. So output it accounts for an **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I tried defining `oper` as `std::string oper`, and while that compiled without errors, opening the `.exe` caused an error: `The procedure entry point _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE7compareRPKc could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\me\Documents\math.exe`

Comment: Sounds like you're having some problems with your linker there. What compiler are you on?

Comment: I'm using mingw's g++ compiler

Comment: Awesome, what compiler flags?

Comment: By the way, can you run the executable within the MinGW/bin directory without a crash?

Comment: `g++ math.cpp -o math.exe`

Comment: What do you mean within the MinGW/bin directory? Like with the .cpp file saved in that directory?

Comment: Well not necessarily. You can do it that way but you can also start it with MinGW/bin as the current working directory.

Comment: Huh yeah it does work perfectly fine in that directory. What causes this?

Comment: So the issue then is that the dynamic library isn't loading properly. Make sure MinGW/bin is on the PATH environment variable. When you compile things with MinGW you have to have its runtime library where you want to run your application.

Comment: I do have it added to the PATH variable and I've restarted my computer after doing so...

Comment: Oh that's strange. Then I don't have much of an idea what might be happening. I guess as a walkaround, you could try linking the CRT statically. I'm not as familiar with MinGW issues, but I'm sure you can find a solution to this somewhere online.

Comment: Solution for future readers: Just copy the `libstdc++-6.dll` file from `MinGW/bin` to the directory of your `.exe`

Comment: Yeah, you will have to redistribute that .dll with your application, so it might be the best approach for you anyways.